# How do I properly make a shape key of a male jaw?

Tags: modeling, mesh, shape-keys

I used my own head as a reference and tried to model it as best as I could, but I just need to know the right form and rotation of the jaw so I can reshape and animate it along with the teeth to do a simple open mouth animation. Kind of like he's yelling, about to bite something, or go to the dentist. Also, I know the eyes are a bit big but that's just for technical purposes.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Pivot point of jaw is just near the hole of the ear.

Image based on Kent Trammel's "Human Realistic" CG Cookie course.

[image]